Exponential integration simplification
Given functions $I(x,t)$ and $v(x,t)$, I want to simplify the expression for $T(x)$, given by
$$
T(x)=\int_0^\infty \exp\left\{-\int_0^t\int_{\xi_+(\tau)}^{\xi_-(\tau)} I(\xi,\tau)\,d\xi d\tau \right\}\,dt
$$
where
$$
\xi_\pm(\tau)=x\mp \int_\tau^t v(\xi_\pm(\tau'),\tau')\,d\tau'
$$
which are solutions to the system
\begin{align}
\frac{d\xi_\pm(\tau)}{d\tau} &= \pm v(\xi_\pm(\tau), \tau)\\
\xi_\pm(t) &= x
\end{align}
Is there any way of simplifying the expression of $T(x)$? If not, under what conditions of $I(x,t)$ or $v(x,t)$ can I simplify $T(x)$, excluding the cases of space-time homogeneity?
